# Launch program with .bat trouble

Tags: java, windows, cmd

I currently run this in a .bat file:

```
java -jar BungeeCord.jar
```

Upon running the .bat file this opens and closes and does not stay open. If I manually go into CMD, cd into the folder and launch the bat file it stays open fine. What's the difference between clicking and opening the .bat file and going into cmd and opening it?

I can tell it doesn't launch as I cannot connect to it at all. I need a way to rectify this so it launches through the .bat by just clicking on it, just now it opens and closes quickly.

Comment: Do you mean the jar finishes, yet the batch command prompt closes?  And in the manual case, the jar finishes and the prompt stays allowing you to see results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will keep the window open after the jar is finished.  I'm unsure what you mean, so I'm not sure if this is what you were looking for.

```
cmd /k java -jar BungeeCord.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is opening and closing immediately, the process is terminating...

What is happening exactly when you open it from command prompt? Is your jar running when this is done?

Try redirecting output to a file like below:

java -jar BungeeCord.jar > out.txt

See the content of out.txt and you can find out what could be the problem...

Comment: @user1372896 : do one thing...just redirect the output from the batch file to a text file like java -jar BungeeCord.jar > out.txt and then see what is being printed in the out.txt file, you'll have a better idea of the problem

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is helpful, I use this script:

```
@ECHO OFF
TITLE LOBBY SERVER
color 0b
SET BINDIR=%~dp0
CD /D "%BINDIR%"



echo ---------------------------------------------------------------------
echo            STARTING UP SERVER, PLEACE WAIT...
echo ---------------------------------------------------------------------
timeout /t 5 /nobreak


:Start-Server
"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Java\jre1.8.0_45\bin\java.exe" -Xincgc -Xmx1G -Xloggc:J:\logs\lobby.log -jar craftbukkit.jar


echo ---------------------------------------------------------------------
echo            SERVER HAS CRASHED!
echo            RESTARTING IN 5 SEKUNDES...
echo ---------------------------------------------------------------------
ping -n 10 127.0.0.1 > NUL


cls
GOTO Start-Server
```

Comment: Dosn't this run the same command repeatedly? It sounded to me like OP was looking to keep the window open after one run.